# asm error "inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'"

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, avr, inline-assembly

I'm trying to use this code for attiny10. Here, I try to use `_delay_loop_2` but it does not work sometime.

```cpp
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define LED_PIN         PB0
#define DELAY_MAX       512
#define DELAY_MIN       1


int
main(void)
{
        uint16_t delay = DELAY_MIN;
        uint8_t dir = 0;

        /* setup */
        DDRB = 0b00000001; // set LED pin as OUTPUT
        PORTB = 0b00000001; // set LED pin to HIGH

        /* loop */
        while (1) {

                PORTB &= ~(_BV(LED_PIN)); // LED off
                _delay_loop_2(delay);

                PORTB |= _BV(LED_PIN); // LED on
                _delay_loop_2(DELAY_MAX - delay);

                if (dir) { // fade-in
                        if (++delay >= (DELAY_MAX - 1)) dir = 0;
                } else { // fade-out
                        if (--delay <= DELAY_MIN) dir = 1;
                }

        }
}
```

But sometimes I get the error.

```
Processing attiny10 (platform: atmelavr; board: attiny10)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/atmelavr/attiny10.html
PLATFORM: Atmel AVR (4.0.0) > ATtiny10
HARDWARE: ATTINY10 1MHz, 32B RAM, 1KB Flash
PACKAGES: 
 - toolchain-atmelavr @ 1.50400.190710 (5.4.0)
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> 
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 0 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
No dependencies
Building in release mode
Compiling .pio/build/attiny10/src/main.o
Linking .pio/build/attiny10/firmware.elf
src/main.cpp: In function 'main':
/Users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr@1.50400.190710/avr/include/util/delay_basic.h:110:3: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'
  );
   ^
/Users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr@1.50400.190710/avr/include/util/delay_basic.h:110:3: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'
  );
   ^
lto-wrapper: fatal error: avr-g++ returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/Users/user/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr@1.50400.190710/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio/build/attiny10/firmware.elf] Error 1
```

My investigation showed the problem is here.

```cpp
void
_delay_loop_1(uint8_t __count)
{
    __asm__ volatile (
        "1: dec %0" "\n\t"
        "brne 1b"
        : "=r" (__count)
        : "0" (__count)
    );
}

void
_delay_loop_2(uint16_t __count)
{
    __asm__ volatile (
        "1: sbiw %0,1" "\n\t"
        "brne 1b"
        : "=w" (__count)
        : "0" (__count)
    );
}
```

But if I change _delay_loop_2 on _delay_loop_1. There is no error anymore. Why does it happen?
I use virtual studio and PlatformIO.

Comment: you should be using _dealy_ms from that header

Comment: see https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/delay_8h.html

Comment: GCC12 is able to compile both those functions as-is.  https://godbolt.org/z/r1b4xfqds both stand-alone and when inlined into a loop in `main`.  So does GCC5.4 (https://godbolt.org/z/fM536efTT).  That's not LTO mode, in case that somehow makes a difference; your build is getting to the LTO stage, not erroring on the first compile.  And these functions are defined in headers so it's not like cross-file inlining was only visible with LTO.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Nope, it fails. See for example https://godbolt.org/z/x4oo7jYzb You missed the ATtiny10 part, or more generally `-mmcu=avrtiny`.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: Yeah, I realized that after seeing your answer the other day.  If the [mcve] had included an actual `g++` command instead of a bunch of Make output, I might have copied the options and eventually figured out / been reminded what ATtiny10 is.  My comment included a Godbolt link so the OP could tweak it to reproduce their error, since I wasn't able to with my limited knowledge of AVR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this bug reported against AVR-LibC: [Extend _delay_loop_2 so it works with AVR_TINY](https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc/pull/902).

Well, it's a pull request actually, so you see the solution to the bug.  After applying the patch to `include/util/delay_basic.h`, `_delay_loop_2` will read:

```cpp
void
_delay_loop_2 (uint16_t __count)
{
#if defined (__AVR_TINY__)
    __asm__ volatile (
        "1: subi %A0,1" "\n\t"
        "   sbci %B0,0" "\n\t"
        "brne 1b"
        : "+d" (__count)
    );
#else
    __asm__ volatile (
        "1: sbiw %0,1" "\n\t"
        "brne 1b"
        : "+w" (__count)
    );
#endif /* AVR_TINY */
}
```

The problem was that register class `w` is empty on reduced Cores, thus just fall back to 2-instruction subtraction with register class `d`.

### However

Better don't use stuff like _delay_loop_2 which is internal helper.

If you want to delay a specific number of cycles specified at compile-time, better use `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/AVR-Built-in-Functions.html